# Best way to remove CSS rounded-corner halo?

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'm getting a tiny rounded corner *halo* effect that I'd like to get rid of. In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pdLsN/), look for the effect in the red circle. Here's a zoom in of the effect:

[image]

I seem to recall a while back reading an article on just this problem. Anyone have a link to that article? Otherwise, any good ways to get rid of the halo?

It is being caused because the `dl` has all four corners rounded. This allows the bottom of the `dl` to be rounded. The `dt` sits over the `dl` and has its `top left` and `top right` corners rounded. But there is a slight overflow of the `dl` curve behind the `dt` curve, causing the halo.

[My solution](http://jsfiddle.net/pdLsN/2/) is to increase the border-radius of the `dl` so that it is hidden behind the `dt` corner. But it seems like a hack and adds a fair amount more CSS. I'm wondering if there is a better solution. Here it is without the halo:

[image]

Comment: I had to use the magnifier just to see what you were talking about

Comment: @qwertymk - sorry about that. i'm a bit of a perfectionist!

Comment: I just added some images to illustrate better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a 2 pixel discrepancy you could add...

```
div.content dt.top {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

But I think your solution is good, it can be improved by using the shorthand version of border radius:

http://jsfiddle.net/DAjWS/

```
border-radius: [topleft] [topright] [bottomright] [bottomleft]
```

The article you are mentioning probably has to do with the combination of border with border-radius (it produces a halo similar to yours), but in your case it's expected. The same thing would happen in a vector editing app if you overlapped two boxes with rounded corners. you just have to find an elegant way of covering the anti-aliasing of the bottom box.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll go with what I'm doing then, but I'll certainly use your suggestion for border-radius shorthand. That will significantly reduce the CSS.

Comment: Found the article! Link is in answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across [the article that I mentioned in my question](http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed). It was linked to from [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/). Essentially, the following webkit CSS will get rid of the bleed (or halo as I called it):

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```

Comment: Good find! however, this still doesn't fix your original problem, since it fixes a div with a border + border-radius, not two rounded divs on top of each other.

Comment: Oh does it? Good to know. I actually hadn't tested it yet, as the solution we discussed is working fine.